# How to check Original file extensions using .Net

Tags: c#

Path.getFileExtension(filepath); will give file extension ,

If i change *.exe to *.dat ,Is there any way to check the original(.exe) extension of the file ?

Comment: No............. Too short for an answer?  :)

Comment: @L.B Well, not directly, at least... Nothing's stopping you from digging into the file in detail

Comment: @ReedCopsey In fact, Not knowing what OP really wants to do is stopping me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to see if the file was originally an .exe, the only real option would be to read the file itself byte by byte, and check to see if it matches the [Portable Executable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) format.

The [file specification for Microsoft Portable Executable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx) is available online.